# Is the download URL permanent?

Tags: firebase-storage

Here's JS code I use to get the download URL:

```
ref.child('penus.jpg').getDownloadURL()
  .then(url => {
     console.log(url)
  })
```

Is this url permanent? Can I share it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL will work until you revoke the token that was assigned to it.  You can do that in the Firebase console.  Other than that, it's permanent and meant to be shared.